# When would one use ssh or http to clone?

Tags: git

When [cloning a Git repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository), one has a couple of options on the url to clone the repository from. For exapmle, `https` and `ssh`.

I understand one would use the `ssh` if the repo is hosted on a private server, but if the project is hosted on Github itself, is there a difference between cloning via `http` or via `ssh`?

Comment: For the most part ssh has much nicer authorization mechanism - just pop your public key up there and you never have to think about it again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is in the protocol used, as you probably guessed. Assuming you don't much care about the technical details between HTTPS and ssh, ssh has the advantage that you can use public key authentication, while you must use a username and password with HTTPS. They both get the repository onto your computer and allow you to interact with remotes in the same way. HTTPS also has the advantage that it tends to play nicer with firewalls than ssh does, though I've never run into a network that prevents me from using ssh.

As @Jeeter's answer explains, Github encourages you to use HTTPS, so go with that if you're in doubt, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging, and found that [Github recommends cloning with `https`](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended):

```
Cloning with HTTPS URLs (recommended)
...
In certain cases, if you'd rather use SSH, you might be able to use SSH over the HTTPS port.
```

But for the most part, they're the same!

Cloning with `ssh` [requires keypair setup on your computer](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh-urls), and is used for locally-hosted repositories:

```
SSH URLs can be used locally, or as a secure way of deploying your code to production servers. You can also use SSH agent forwarding with your deploy script to avoid managing keys on the server.
```